# How to specify the last column of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix A, how can I represent the last column, since I want to sort the matrix based on that.

Comment: `A[, ncol(A)] ` or `A[, ncol(A), drop = FALSE]` to keep to matrix structure

Comment: Why not to name your column? It is better/safer to work with names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
> A <- matrix(rnorm(16), 4, 4)
> ncol(A)
[1] 4
> # Get the last column
> A[,ncol(A)]
[1]  0.7593943  0.0726012  2.2784912 -0.2571095
> # If you want to sort based on the last column...
> A[order(A[,ncol(A)]),]
           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -0.9013910 -0.06612518 -1.51267548 -0.2571095
[2,]  0.3851738 -0.81303780  0.01062751  0.0726012
[3,] -1.6940473 -1.15323294 -1.50261705  0.7593943
[4,]  0.3120409 -0.30047966  0.59672449  2.2784912
```

Answer (score 5):

If A is your matrix then the last column of A is:

```
A[,ncol(A)]
```

If you are not familiar with bracket indexing in R, this code selects all rows of A (since the space before the comma is blank) and then the last column of A since R indexing begins at 1 (unlike languages like Python). `ncol(A)` returns the number of columns in A as an integer so indexing in this way gives your desired result.